# I can't call constructor of inner class with this pointer of outer class

Tags: c++, inner-classes, const-correctness, this-pointer, function-qualifier

I don't know why below code failed to compile with error:

> "no instance of constructor "cb::iterator::iterator" matches the
>   argument list argument types are:(int, const cb)"

But the code compiles fine when i uncomment the second version of constructor!
why compiler considers `*this` as const?

```
class cb
{
public:
    class iterator
    {
    public:
        iterator(int x, cb& c):cb_(c)  { x_ = x; }
        //iterator(int x, const cb& c) :cb_(c) { x_ = x; }

    private:
            int x_;
            //cb a;
            const cb& cb_;
    };

    iterator begin() const; 
};

cb::iterator cb::begin() const
{
    return iterator(1, *this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `class X`, the type of `this` pointer is `X* const` if a member function of X is declared as `const`. So the parameter of constructor in this case should to be `const` too.

Here is a full explanation:
['this' pointer in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/this-pointer-in-c/)